# tinymce - image/file upload default to images

Tags: javascript, yii2, tinymce

I have copied the image plugin to customize it upload video, which is working fine.

but when I select upload - it defaults to selection of image files, I tried searching everywhere, but couldn't find,how I can change this to type mp4 or of type video files.

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE has the [Media plugin](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/media/) which allows you to natively upload video and audio files. It should work without any customizations to the Image plugin, thus - safer. However, to be able to upload something other than images, you will need to add a [`file_picker_callback`](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/file-image-upload/#file_picker_callback) that will handle uploads.